# I want to commit but also create branch in git. Is this the correct way?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I have 3 files unstaged.
What I want is to commit and push 2 of them and save the 3rd in a private branch.
If I do git add/git commit for the 2 of them, then git checkout branch name and then git checkout master and THEN git pull followed by  git push am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

For concreteness, you are on `master`, and you have three files:

```
.../file1
.../file2
.../file3
```

where the `...` parts are any path within the repo, and I'll leave them out below.

The first two files are new (you just created them) or existing (you modified them), it doesn't matter in this case.

Meanwhile `file3` is also either new or modified, but that *may* make a difference below.

The first part is definitely right: `git add file1 file2; git commit` will make a new commit containing the two new-or-modified files (and all the other files already in the repo), but not containing `file3` (if it's new), or not containing the changes to `file3` (if it already exists).

As soon as the commit with `file1` and `file2` is done, you can probably push the new `master`:

```
git push origin master
```

It doesn't matter that you have not done anything with `file3` yet, or which branch you are on when you do the above; by specifying that you want to push local branch `master` to `origin`'s `master`, you can at least *try* this push any time.  (That's what the two extra arguments are for.  The `origin` part is "where it's going", and the `master` part means the same as `master:master`, which means "push local `master` -> remote `master`".)  Or, you can delay this if you like, and we'll get to that in a moment.  More importantly, this might fail with a "rejected" message, in which case you'll pretty much *have* to delay it while you commit `file3` somewhere.

Now, as for `file3`, the situation is a little more complicated.  You want to "save it in a private branch", OK, we can do that, but: is it a completely new file, or did it already exist?  If completely new things are easy.  If it already existed, then there's one or two more questions: is this private branch a *new* branch, or an existing (private) branch?  If it's an existing branch, does the file differ between "whatever branch you're on now" and "that other branch you want it on"?

For a new branch or new file, there won't be any issues here.  Just do:

```
git checkout -b new_private_branch    # create new private branch
git add file3
git commit
```

Or:

```
git checkout existing_private_branch
git add file3
git commit
```

If there's no change between whatever branch you're on now, and an existing private branch, that second command will also work.  But, if `file3` is in your current branch, and is also in `existing_private_branch`, and is *different* between the two, you'll get:

```
error: ... would be overwritten by checkout:
    file3
```

when you try to move to the existing private branch.  This is because git needs to overwrite the work-tree version of `file3` in order to move to that branch.

If that's the case, you'll need to save the modified `file3` (or the changes to `file3`) somewhere that `git checkout` *won't* overwrite, and then make the working-directory `file3` either clean, or non-existent.  There are a number of ways to do that (e.g., `mv file3 another_name` versus `git stash`), with various different advantages and disadvantages.

I'm guessing `file3` is new, and/or the private branch is new, so there's no point in going into more details here.  Anyway, let's assume you've properly saved away `file3` on `private_branch`.  That means you did a `git commit` on that private branch and `git status` shows that everything is clean.

### git pull, git fetch, git merge, and/or git rebase

Everything's cleaned up locally and you can now do:

```
git checkout master
```

to get back on master.

If someone else has beaten you to a `git push`, and you try your `git push origin master` now (instead of earlier), you'll get an error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

This means, they beat you to it.  They put something into `master` that you don't have yet.  You need to get it, and how you get it is `git fetch`.

If you *don't* get a `rejected`, nobody beat you to anything and you're in great shape and you are all done!  So you don't need any `pull` or `fetch`-then-`merge` or anything.  You're more likely to beat the other guy to it if you do your `git push origin master` earlier, above.  But if you tried earlier and it failed, or you try now and it fails, now is the time to do something.

#### git pull

The `git pull` command really means `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (unless you configure it to do a rebase).  I prefer not to use `git pull` much—I like separate `fetch`-then-decide steps.  Even if you use `git pull` anyway, let's break it down into `fetch` and `merge` parts.

#### git fetch

I like to type the `origin` part here too:

```
git fetch origin
```

Unless you've configured git a bunch, `fetch` will assume `origin` anyway, so you can leave out the `origin` part; I just like to be explicit.

This is where those ASCII diagrams of commits come in handy.  After the first `git push` attempt fails (is "rejected") and you do a `git fetch`, this is what you wind up with.  Each letter represents some commit.  Commits `A` and `B` are what you started with.  Commit `C` is the one *you* made for `file1` and `file2`.  Commit `D` is the one "they" (whoever beat you to it) made.  Your private branch is also "coming off B", but I won't bother drawing it here.

```
... - A - B - D       <-- origin/master
            \
              C        <-- master, HEAD=master
```

The push gets "rejected" because you're asking the remote to move `origin/master` to point to `C`.  From `C`, the history goes back to `B`, and git only follows these lines "up and/or backwards" so there's no link from `B` to `D`.  That would leave commit `D` all lonely and forgotten.

At this point you have two easy(ish) options.  You can `git merge`.  Since you're on `master` now, and `master` tracks `origin/master`, this mean the same as the long form:

```
git merge origin/master
```

That tells git to merge *your* current branch (i.e., `master`) with the one you just "fetch"-ed, `origin/master`.  If the merge goes well it automatically `git commit`-s the merge and now you have something that the remote will be happy with.  Diagram-wise, it makes this new commit E:

```
... - A - B - D        <-- origin/master
            \   \
              C - E    <-- master, HEAD=master
```

Now `git push origin master` will succeed.  Making `origin/master` point to `E` is OK, because `E` points up-and-back to *both* `C` *and* `D`.  But, it does mean you've made a merge-commit that you could probably have avoided.  Whether you *should* avoid it is a policy decision, more than a technical one (so nobody but your boss can tell you to do this one way or another :-) ).

Your other option is to use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

(As with `git merge`, you can actually leave out the `origin/master` part, because `master` is tracking `origin/master`.)

What this does is take the commit you made earlier—the one adding `file1` and `file2`—and "figure out what changed" in the process (i.e., what you changed in those files), and make that same change to `origin/master`.  If all goes well, it leaves your old commit behind (it's Still In There, git saves everything for a long time) and makes a *new* commit.  The result is this:

```
... - A - B - D        <-- origin/master
           \    \
            \     C2   <-- master, HEAD=master
             \
              C        [no label]
```

The changes in old-commit-`C` (`file1` and `file2`) are now also in new-commit-`C2`.  Unlike `C` though, `C2` is "on top of" `origin/master`.  So now `git push origin master` will succeed, and everyone (including you) will eventually forget all about `C` and just use `C2` and the history will just look like `A - B - D - C2`.  It's not really any "better" than the merge version, but it's simpler to look at and (sometimes) to think about.

Comment: +1.Very nice answer.One question, in the first time we do `git push` where you say:`As soon as the commit with file1 and file2 is done, you can probably push the new master` if I do a `git push` in a repos with a lot of activity won't it fail?That is my issue.I need to do a `git pull` first.You are right.It is a modified file to a **new** branch

Comment: "Probably" might be an overstatement.  It depends on how active `master` is and how long it's taken between your most recent fetch+merge ("pull") for you to make the two changes.  But you can always try it and see if it gets rejected as a non-fast-forward.

Comment: :I tried it and code has been pushed.The repos is very active

Comment: OK, well, now you get to choose between "git merge" and "git rebase", for putting your file1+file2 changes in.

Comment: "Should" is one of those words containing a policy decision (merge vs rebase), but depending on the project in question, pretty much, yes.